# How to use Fixed Length subnetting for Class C network?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, network

This was an exam question last year, and I was trying to figure out how to get the answer:

A small company is assigned the class C network 205.67.35.0. You need to divide
this network to provide subnets for three departments using fixed-length
subnetting. The departments are approximately the same size. Show the network
and broadcast addresses for each subnet. Show the slash notation. How many hosts
are on each subnet? Are the resulting subnets class C networks?

How would you go about doing this? How would you start it?

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here. By the way, network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Please let them rest in peace. Modern networking doesn't use network classes.

Answer (score 3):

Classful subnetting has been deprecated 25 years ago. Any exam that still asks about class A, B or C addresses is dangerously obsolete and should not be taken seriously. I strongly recommend to find an educator who has updated their training material less than a quarter of a century ago...

Comment: While I agree completely, this ought to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ron: I used to agree, but classful subnetting questions  come up so often thati felt that giving a canonical "just don't" answer was becoming appropriate :)